# Mobaxterm icons and features

Tags: mobaxterm

[Picture: Mobaxterm icons with arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfkX2.png)

I have recently downloaded Mobaxterm (latest stable version 10.2) windows installer.

After successfully installed the software, comparing with the demo video available at its official website (http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/demo.html), I found the icons of "Tools, Games, Sessions, View, Split" buttons of my installed version appear to be different from those in the demo video in the way that:

in the demo video, those button all have a "green down arrow at the right bottom conner" (please see those icons highlighted in yellow circles in the picture).
In addition, the "split" button in the demo had a "golden lightning bolt" going right through the middle of the icon, whereas mine did not have that.
My questions are:

Are those the differences between free version and professional version?
I've seen people split out more than 4 terminals in Mobaxterm, but I could not find that option in mine. Is this also a limitation of the free version?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found answer to some of my questions.

Question:
I've seen people split out more than 4 terminals in Mobaxterm, but I could not find that option in mine. Is this also a limitation of the free version?

Answer:
The behaviour I saw which people split out more than 4 terminals was under "MultiExecute" mode.

How-to:
To do that, just open up the number of terminals that you want, and then click "MultipExec" button at the tool bar.

Other:
As far as I know, this functionality is only available in multiExecute mode by clicking "MultiExec" button but not supported in normal window split mode by clicking "Split" button.